# website mobile menu broken on safari browser

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari

I'm working on this project: https://kickit.gr/ and I have an issue with the mobile menu of the homepage (only!), on safari browser.

When the hamburger button is clicked, the menu, even though it opens and is clickable, it is invisible!

The mobile menu is effective < 750px screen width.

I don't own an iphone and the debugging through sites with virtual safari browsers isn't that effective. I have tried changing some css, but with no luck...

You can check the problem on the live site.

Here is most of the relative code:

```js
function hamburgerButtonClick() {
  var hamburger = $('.hamburger');
  var menu = $('.menu');

  var is_active = 'is-active';
  var mobile_menu = 'mobile_menu';

  if (!hamburger.hasClass(is_active)) {
    hamburger.addClass(is_active);
    menu.addClass(mobile_menu);
  } else {
    hamburger.removeClass(is_active);
    hamburger.removeClass(mobile_menu);
    menu.removeClass(mobile_menu);
  }
}
```

```css
.sticky_menu .menu {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}

.mobile_menu {
  display: block !important;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  background: #191b1a;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="sticky_menu" id="sticky_menu">
  <div class="menu_holder">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--spin" type="button" onclick="hamburgerButtonClick()">
                <span class="hamburger-box">
                    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                </span>
            </button>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="social_menu_mobile"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

the .is_active class is used for the animation of the icon of the hamburger-menu, i don't believe it is relevant to the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently there are some issues with `overflow: hidden` in Safari iOS.

I removed the property targeting the  node, in the header_frontpage.css. Now it works as intended.